# Set mecanim animation playback time/position

Tags: c#, animation, unity3d-mecanim

I'm trying to set an animator's playback time.  (or, start an animation at a specific time)  I haven't had success with either approach.

**Note**: I am setting the Animator (an) in the Start().

**Code I've tried:**

```
Public Animator an;

public void SetTime(float time)
{
    an.playbackTime = time;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I guess this one was pretty easy!

I didn't see the constructor options for the Play() method!

**The answer:**

```
an.Play("YourAnimation", 0, 0.4f);
```

However, I am still currious why my original code didn't work.  So I figured out how to make an animation play/start at a specific time... Does anyone know how to basically "rewind" an animation to a specific point? (while it's playing)